# Java ANTLR 4 Listener enter-methods don't get called

Tags: java, listener, antlr4

I'm shamelessly stealing the (slightly edited) title of [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40732255/java-antlr-4-listener-class-methods-dont-get-called) as I'm having the same problem, and said question hasn't been answered yet (it's almost a year old).

Summary: the `enter***` methods of my listener doesn't work. I'm able to increment a counter with the `visitTerminal` method, and I've tested `enterEveryRule` (as in the other question) which also works. But `enterVariableDeclaration` isn't doing anything, and even `enterInit` isn't called.

For clarity: `init` is my grammar's top rule. I'm able to get a graphical representation of this tree/rule when using `TestRig`.

The code for my listener:

```
class MyListener extends MyGrammarBaseListener {

    private int terminalCounter = 0;
    private List<String> variables = new ArrayList<>();


    @Override
    public void visitTerminal(TerminalNode node) {
        terminalCounter++;
    }

    @Override
    public void enterVariableDeclaration(MyGrammarParser.VariableDeclarationContext ctx) {
        variables.add(ctx.getText());
    }

    @Override
    public void enterInit(JavaExamGrammarParser.InitContext ctx) {
        System.out.println("init");
    }

    int getTerminalNodeCount() {
        return terminalCounter;
    }

    List<String> getVariables() {
        return variables;
    }

}
```

The output is simply:

```
143
0
```

where `143` is the number of terminal nodes and `0` is the size of `variables`; `"init"` isn't printed, even if that node/rule is *definitely* visited.

And for the tree in question, there should be at least a handful of declarations (can verify this by looking at the graphical tree).

Any help or tips?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This has happened to me before when I changed the root rule during the development of my grammar.  Are you sure your tree walker is starting at rule `init`?

Comment: I've never changed my top/root rule, so that shouldn't be the case.

Comment: It might help to share your grammar with us... And what version of ANTLR are you using?

Comment: Check my answer below. I simply made a rookie mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In some ways, just posting to StackOverflow helps, even if no answer is provided.
Especially when the problem is your own doing...

There was nothing wrong with Antlr (I'm using 4.7, btw) there was nothing wrong with the grammar, and there was nothing wrong with the listener. It turns out that the project has two *very similar* grammars with two *very similar* names; I was using the wrong match-up of grammars and listeners.

Comment: Ah, the good old [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)-method. :)

Comment: Rubber duck indeed. Thanks for being my ducks ^.^